# explore, netrw: How to navigate to a file / folder starting with "abc"

Tags: netrw, filesystem

Is there any way to jump to a file / folder starting with a given set of characters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regular search works fine, something went wrong last time when I tried to use it.

`/^folder_name`